# Cloudfoundry TCP connections on port 4443

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to open a TCP connection from cloudfoundry application.
As I came to know that Cloudroundtry doesn't support TCP ports yet.

However in the documentation here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#ports

It says under `Port Limitations`

> The default cf-release manifest assigns port 4443 for TCP/WebSocket communications.

Does this mean that I can open TCP connection on port `4443`, I have tried running a ServerSocket on 4443, however this port is not accessible from outside cloudfoundry machine.

I'm aware of the long polling, WebSocket and Servlet 3.1 non blocking full duplex method. However I don't want to implement these if I can simply use port `4443` for direct TCP connections.

Please confirm if it's possible to use this port for TCP connections, if not then what does the documentation above mean ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation above is stating that, by default, port 4443 is used as a WebSocket port to be forwarded to the Cloud Foundry router. This port is not what your application would listen on, but is the external port a client would connect to, e.g. `run.pivotal.io:4443`. This means that you cannot have a direct TCP connection to your app using it, since the router expects an HTTP request upgrade.

There has been ongoing work to enable TCP routing on Cloud Foundry, and the functionality should start to become available on certain Cloud Foundry installations in the near future. More information can be found on our github repo: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/routing-release.

Comment: Does that mean I can't open a `WebSocket` connection too ? Like `ws://host:80` or `ws://host:4443` ? If I intend to upgrade request protocol should I send the request to `4443` port ?